# How to convert "setCompletionHandler" code from Objective-C to Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a code in Objective-C as example:

```
VKShareDialogController * shareDialog = [VKShareDialogController new]; //1 
shareDialog.text = @"This post created using #vksdk #ios"; //2 
shareDialog.vkImages = @[@"-10889156_348122347",@"7840938_319411365",@"-60479154_333497085"]; //3 
shareDialog.shareLink = [[VKShareLink alloc] initWithTitle:@"Super puper link, but nobody knows" link:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://vk.com/dev/ios_sdk"]]; //4 
[shareDialog setCompletionHandler:^(VKShareDialogControllerResult result) { 
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; 
}]; //5 
[self presentViewController:shareDialog animated:YES completion:nil]; //6
```

I have successfully converted everything to swift except this:

```
[shareDialog setCompletionHandler:^(VKShareDialogControllerResult result) { 
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I tried like this:

```
    let share = VKShareDialogController()
    share.text = "123"
    let img = VKUploadImage(image: UIImage(named: "bg"), andParams: nil)
    imgArray.append(img)
    let link = NSURL(string: "www.ya.ru")
    share.shareLink = VKShareLink(title: "Preved", link: link)
    share.uploadImages = imgArray

    share.completionHandler { result : VKShareDialogControllerResult) -> Void

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }

    self.presentViewController(share, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and like this:

[image]

and nothing worked for me. Also I have a suggestion from Xcode which look like this:

[image]

Maybe someone knows how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error is pointing out to you that it can't parse that line of code. And that's happening because you're missing an opening parenthesis, `(`. You're also missing the `in` keyword.

Also, as luk2302 pointed out, you're assigning a value to a property, so you need `=` in there, too.

Thus it should be:

```
share.completionHandler = { (result : VKShareDialogControllerResult) -> Void in
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

or

```
share.completionHandler = { result in
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Are you missing the assignment operator `=` or can you omit him in this case?

Comment: No, you're quite right. I was focusing on the syntactic errors within the closure and wasn't looking the broader context. I've corrected that.

Comment: There were just too many missing characters in a lot of places :P